# SQL sum function (unexpected SUM_SYM, expecting END_OF_INPUT))

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sum, case

I am trying to write a sum function that should look something like this:

```
sum(case when (tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operation cost%" OR tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Added to operational cost%")
        then CAST(int, substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(tblhistorique.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), '.', 1))
        when (tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operation cost%" OR tblhistorique.REMARQUE LIKE "Removed from operational cost%") 
        then CAST(int, substring_index( LTRIM(substring_index(tblhistorique.REMARQUE, 'Qty:', -1)), ' ', 1))*(-1) else 0 end)
```

What it does essentially is go into a table check what kind of statement is in the REMARQUE column, if its added we want to add the QTY if its removed then we want to minus the QTY.

To get the QTY out of the string a little bit of string manipulation needed to be done that's what you see with the substring_index and all that.  That seems to work fine.

I have 2 questions, can I do summations on strings of numbers in SQL because I can go arithmetic with them which i found very strange? and what is wrong with the way im using this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do "arithmetic with [strings]" in MySQL, because MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers in an arithmetic context.  It converts the string `'123'` to the number `123`, for instance.  It will also convert `'123abc'` to `123`.  It uses the leading digits, so `'abc123'` is converted to `0`.

This would also work for summation, because that would be an arithmetic context.

Perhaps the problem with your expression is the following:

```
CAST(int,  . . .)
```

The correct syntax is:

```
CAST(. . . as unsigned)
```

You can do the same thing with:

```
. . . + 0
```

Comment: still the same problem even if I change the syntax, I think it might be the way I am using my sum function.  Maybe what I am telling to sum doesnt really sum up? I dont know

Comment: @user1923086 . . . There is no `sum()` function in the code in your question.

Comment: the code in the question is a snippet from a larger sql statement, the sum() is the outermost function.